# Authenticate player ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I am trying to integrate game center into my app, however I keep getting errors. I input the following code into app delegate.m and this is what i get:

```
- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer {
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
            _gameCenterManager = YES;

            // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else{
                    leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                }
            }];
        }

        else{
            _gameCenterManager = NO;
        }
    }
};
```

}

I use this code, but I get an error for this part of the code:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Xcode tells me that this instance method is not found. From my understanding this is an instance method from UIView? Is there anyway I could somehow use this method in the app delegate class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to @Raptor's answer try following.

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];` to present a view controller in App Delegate, as App Delegate does not respond to `presentViewController:animated:`

You can use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```